# How can I calculate an "active users" aggregation from an activity log in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, I have a table that logs activity for all users, with an account ID and a timestamp field:

```sql
SELECT account_id, created FROM activity_log;
```

A single `account_id` can appear many times in a day, or not at all.

I would like a chart showing the number of "active users" each day, where "active users"
means "users who have done any activity within the previous X days".

If X is 1, then we can just truncate timestamp to 'day' and aggregate:

```sql
SELECT date_trunc('day', created) AS date, count(DISTINCT account_id) 
FROM activity_log
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', created) ORDER BY date;
```

If X is exactly 7, then we could truncate to 'week' and aggregate - although this gives
me only one data point for a week, when I actually want one data point per day.

But I need to solve for the general case of different X, and give a distinct data point for each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to generate the dates and then count using `left join` and `group by` or similar logic.  The following uses a lateral join:

```
select gs.dte, al.num_accounts
from generate_series('2021-01-01'::date, '2021-01-31'::date, interval '1 day'
                    ) gs(dte) left join lateral
     (select count(distinct al.account_id) as num_accounts
      from activity_log al
      where al.created >= gs.dte - (<n - 1>) * interval '1 day' and
            al.created < gs.dte + interval '1 day'
     ) al
     on 1=1
order by gs.dte;
```

`<n - 1>` is one less than the number of days.  So for one week, it would be `6`.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to get day wise distinct account_id for last X days you can use below query. Instead of **7** you can use any number as you wise:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', created) AS date, count(DISTINCT account_id) 
FROM activity_log
where date_trunc('day', created)>=date_trunc('day',CURRENT_DATE) +interval '-7' day  
GROUP BY date_trunc('day', created) 
ORDER BY date
```

(If there is no activity in any given date then the date will not be in the output.)